# Is it possible to programmaticaly change the HTML rendered by Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, theming

Imagine that we have a project completely finished, with lots of modules, themes, etc. Is it possible at all to have a module, which will be called at the last stage, and change the HTML output. For example, we want to make a ereg_replace of a img tag, and we don't want to deep into the modules. Is there a simple hook which can accomplish this extremely simple task ?

Comment: What specifically do you want to change?  There's probably a hook for whatever you want to change, but there's not one universal hook for everything.

Comment: Putting aside the various reasons why that's a terrible idea (which I'm sure you're already aware of), yes, it's technically possible. How you would do it depends on what you need to change.

Comment: Well, I wanted to change the behaviour of a link in a View. So the link is dynamical, now you can only choose a substitution pattern (another field), and I would like to change dynamically. And had no chance of changing the display of the view for a single result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alter the rendered content of a page, you start by adding a `post_render` function to the node:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view_alter().
 */
function MODULE_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  $build['#post_render'][] = 'MODULE_wrap_images';
}
```

And then in that post render function, you can do what you need to do. In the example below, I am replacing `float:left` and `float:right` with a wrapper div:

```
function MODULE_wrap_images($content) {
  // Find all links within the content and extract the complete <img> tag.
  if (preg_match_all('#<img.*?/>#i', $content, $matches)) {

    // Loop matches and process.
    foreach ($matches[0] as $index => $match) {

      // Align images left.
      if (stripos($match, 'float: left;')) {
        $new = '<div class="content-img content-img-left">' . str_ireplace('float: left;', '', $match) . '</div>';
        $content = str_ireplace($match, $new, $content);
      }

      // Align images right.
      if (stripos($match, 'float: right;')) {
        $new = '<div class="content-img content-img-right">' . str_ireplace('float: right;', '', $match) . '</div>';
        $content = str_ireplace($match, $new, $content);
      }
    }
  }

  return $content;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Same approach for altering the HTML for the entire page:

For Drupal 7:

`// Implement HOOK_page_alter.
function MY_MODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  // Add our processing to the #post_render functions.
  $page['#post_render'][] = 'MY_MODULE_page_post_render';
}`

function MY_MODULE_page_post_render($html) {
  // Do something to the HTML for the page.
  $html = str_replace('apples', 'oranges', $html);
  return $html;
}